# Inserting a figure of entire one page in between two pages

Tags: tables, floats, alignment

I have multiple big single-page figures/table in my document which is a two-column conference paper. Until now I had put these figures/table at the end of my document. Now that I have finished my draft I would like to insert these figures/table in appropriate places without disturbing the layout of the rest of the pages. When I insert them now the sections break and a lot of empty space are produced. Is there a way to insert one-page figures/table without disturbing the layout of the other pages. ?  My minimum effort code is this

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
%########################## works with both lipsum and blindtext AND real text.
\section{Dummy 1}
\lipsum[1-3]
\section{Dummy 2}
\textcolor{red}{Hello again \lipsum[3-6] and again}
\section{Dummy 3}
\textcolor{purple}{Hello again \lipsum[7-14] and again}
\subsection{Dummy 3a}
\textcolor{brown}{Hello again \lipsum[15-17] and again}
%\blindtext[1]



\newcommand{\dummyfigure}{\tikz \fill [NavyBlue] (0,0) rectangle node [black] {Figure} (2,2);}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}


    \begin{table*}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{cM{40mm}M{40mm}M{40mm}M{40mm}}
            \toprule
            Nr. & Case 1 & Case 2 & Case 3 & Case 4 \\
            \midrule
            \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Parameter 1} & \dummyfigure \caption*{(a)}\label{a} & \dummyfigure \caption*{(b)}\label{b} & \dummyfigure  \caption*{(c)}\label{c}& \dummyfigure \caption*{(d)}\label{d}\\
            \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Parameter 2} & \dummyfigure \caption*{(e)}\label{e} & \dummyfigure \caption*{(f)}\label{f} & \dummyfigure \caption*{(g)}\label{g} & \dummyfigure \caption*{(h)}\label{h} \\
            \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Parameter 3} & \dummyfigure \caption*{(i)}\label{i} & \dummyfigure \caption*{(j)}\label{j} & \dummyfigure \caption*{(k)}\label{k} & \dummyfigure \caption*{(l)}\label{l}\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Table of figures}
        \label{tbl:table_of_figures}
    \end{table*}


\end{document}
```

I would like to move the figures/table in page 3 between page 1 and 2. Kindly guide.

Comment: From the documentation of IEEEtran: "IEEE authors are warned
not to use packages that allow material to be placed across the
middle of the two text columns (such as cuted.sty, midfloat.sty,
etc.) as the IEEE does not do this." So what you want to do as described in your question is not a good idea in general and will probably have to be changed after submission.

Comment: If you want to place the table on page 2, then you should write the code of the table on page 1 as stated in the 'IEEEtran How To' - "Another LATEX 2e" limitation (patched with stfloats or not) is that double column floats will not appear on the same page where they are defined. So, the user will have to define such things prior to the page on which they are to (possibly) appear."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert the table in the document (before `\section{Dummy 3}`, the table will not fit in the remaining space of page #1 and will go to page #2), then  add vertical space to fill the rest the page.

[image: d]

Observe that if you remove everything from  `\centering`  to `\label` inside the `table*` (but not the `\vspace`) , you will get a blank page #2.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}

\newcommand{\dummyfigure}{\tikz \fill [NavyBlue] (0,0) rectangle node [black] {Figure} (2,2);}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
    %########################## works with both lipsum and blindtext AND real text.

    \section{Dummy 1}
    \lipsum[1-3]
    
    \section{Dummy 2}
    \textcolor{red}{Hello again \lipsum[3-6] and again} 

    \begin{table*}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{cM{40mm}M{40mm}M{40mm}M{40mm}}
            \toprule
            Nr. & Case 1 & Case 2 & Case 3 & Case 4 \\
            \midrule
            \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Parameter 1} & \dummyfigure \caption*{(a)}\label{a} & \dummyfigure \caption*{(b)}\label{b} & \dummyfigure  \caption*{(c)}\label{c}& \dummyfigure \caption*{(d)}\label{d}\\
            \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Parameter 2} & \dummyfigure \caption*{(e)}\label{e} & \dummyfigure \caption*{(f)}\label{f} & \dummyfigure \caption*{(g)}\label{g} & \dummyfigure \caption*{(h)}\label{h} \\
            \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Parameter 3} & \dummyfigure \caption*{(i)}\label{i} & \dummyfigure \caption*{(j)}\label{j} & \dummyfigure \caption*{(k)}\label{k} & \dummyfigure \caption*{(l)}\label{l}\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Table of figures}
        \label{tbl:table_of_figures}
        \vspace{\textheight}    % fill the remainig space of the page               
    \end{table*}

    \section{Dummy 3}
    \textcolor{purple}{Hello again \lipsum[7-14] and again}
    
    \subsection{Dummy 3a}
    \textcolor{brown}{Hello again \lipsum[15-17] and again}
    %\blindtext[1]
    
\end{document}
```